# Why is it my txt file keeps looping non stop?

Tags: java, text-files, continue

I have been rushing my assignment and I found this bug when I'm doing a removing procedure of the membership. So, what's wrong with the code? Eventually, when I key in the member ID, it keeps on looping non stop. I tested it with a `println` and it keeps on printing.

```
  while(scC.hasNext()){
  removeMemId = scC.next();
  removeName = scC.next();
  removeAddress = scC.next();
  removeIcNo = scC.next();
  removePhoneNo = scC.next();
  removeMemberType = scC.next().charAt(0);
  removeScanDate = scC.next();
  removeExpiryDate = scC.next();
  removeYoga = scC.nextInt();
  removeKickboxing = scC.nextInt();
  removeAerobics = scC.nextInt();

  if(iRemoveMemId.equals(removeMemId))
  continue;

  else{



            FileWriter fileWriteRemove = new FileWriter(fileCorporate2.getName(),true);
            BufferedWriter buffWriteRemove = new BufferedWriter(fileWriteRemove);
            buffWriteRemove.write(removeMemId+",");
            buffWriteRemove.write(removeName+",");
            buffWriteRemove.write(removeIcNo+",");
            buffWriteRemove.write(removeAddress+",");
            buffWriteRemove.write(removePhoneNo+",");
            buffWriteRemove.write(removeMemberType+",");
            buffWriteRemove.write(removeScanDate+",");
            buffWriteRemove.write(removeExpiryDate+",");
            buffWriteRemove.write(removeYoga+",");
            buffWriteRemove.write(removeKickboxing+",");
            buffWriteRemove.write(removeAerobics+",");
            buffWriteRemove.close();
             }

  }
    scC.close();
    removeCorporate.close();
    fileCorporate.delete();
    fileCorporate2.renameTo(fileCorporate);
    System.out.println("Your membership has been succesfully removed.");
    System.out.println("You will be redirect back to home page\n\n");
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger?

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov what's a debugger ? I've never heard of it before. I just had this subject 2 months ago.

Comment: Start here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html for example

Comment: It is most certainly incorrect to open, write one line and close the buffWriteRemove individually for each set of removeXyz strings. The file must be opened and closed in parallel with the one from which you read using the Scanner scC.

Comment: Well, I think its the file.txt name problem..

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call next() more than once in a while loop.

You can store next() as a temporary variable, then use the variable for your iteration

Use something like this:

```
  while(scC.hasNext()){
  Object temp = scC.next();
  removeMemId =temp;
  removeName = temp;
  removeAddress = temp;
  removeIcNo = temp;
  removePhoneNo = temp;
  removeMemberType = temp.charAt(0);   
  .....
```

It may not necessarily be the cause of your problem though.

Comment: but incompatible types error came out if I changed it

Comment: Well, I don't know the types of your variables. You can replace 'Object ' by your specific type (I assume, it's a String). Also, you can try to parse the others to match. For example, for an Integer you can do Integer.parseInt(temp) instead of scC.nextInt().